# How can I achieve a wind efffect?

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

How can I achieve a wind effect like this.(See link in comments).

Not the SKFieldNode, I'm looking to achieve the design.

How can I do it using PARTICLES?

I've tried playing with the SMOKE template in the PARTICLE EDITOR. I tried changing the different parameters/numbers in the editor yet couldn't achieve this effect.

I really need help, I've been trying to do this for weeks.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
I'm looking to achieve 2 different effects in the video.

Adding 2 images to be more precise about what I'm looking for.

1) [Straight/Wavy Wind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXqTa.jpg) - The straight/wavy wind(see in video in the place I drew because it has very low opacity)

2) [Swirly/Hurricane Wind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2umY.jpg) - The swirly/hurricane kind of wind that spins around in swirly motion.

I hope this edit will be the most helpful.

Comment: That is too generic of a question to ask,  you should probably talk to a designer on how to achieve the graphics, and come up with a solution that works best for you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because has to do with design of graphics, not code

Comment: I disagree, because this could be achieved through using SKParticles or SKEmitter @Knight0fDragon

Comment: If you want it to be done using an emitter, then write a very specific question asking for it to be done in an emitter.  The SO model is specific questions that yield specific answers.  Also show some work on what you have attempted to do with emitters, and where you went wrong.

Comment: okay i will edit my question

Comment: In that video, there's a LOT of things going on. Can you specify two things: 1. Which of the things happening in that scene do you want to replicate? 2. Why don't you want to use SKFieldNode/Physics with particles?

Comment: To be a little fairer, @Knight0fDragon, I think asking someone to show where they went wrong is a big ask. Most people suffering through a problem only have a vague idea what's the problem, and very few clues on where they're going wrong. If they knew, they know how to begin solving their problem.

Comment: @Confused Asking someone where they went wrong is not a big ask.  Do you go to the doctors and say I am sick, but I do not know where I am sick?  No, you need to have a general understanding of where something is wrong before anyone can help you.  Please stop going off topic on questions and causing debates.

Comment: It's not offtopic, at all. You bring the focus on your particular view, and state it as a rule of the site and your vision of how the site should be, and how the OPs should be, do, etc. You have stated you believe in the school of "hard knocks" and ruthless teaching. Etc. That's a subjective reality, whether you know it or not. What's not subjective, this guy is struggling to figure out where he is, how to ask questions and what's appropriate. In that mix, knowing what he's doing wrong in an effort to make something fake, like a wind effect, is a big ask. Also objective. How could he know?

Comment: And when you ask someone to state where they're going wrong, when this is exactly what Dunning-Kruger is all about, that those that don't know simply don't know... well, come on. Be considerate. It's not a site rule that someone know where they're going wrong, only that they know they're going wrong - as per your example "I'm sick, here!". This guy has gotten that far... want to make this... can't. Much pain, here! Now he needs help shaping the question because he's past exasperation and inside exhaustion, frustration and extreme irritation.

Comment: thank you @Confused once again. I know how to make the skfieldnode that's why i don't need help doing that, I am looking to do just the wind particles that come out of the fan. btw, physics with particles might be an option I just don't know what it is, how to do it or how it works...

Comment: @YannaiHarel please answer my question: Which of the things happening in that scene do you want to replicate? Take screenshots, and circle EXACTLY what you're wanting to replicate. I see a lot of things moving around in that scene, in different ways.

Comment: Don't use words. Take a screenshot, and be VERY exact in highlighting. Each thing in that scene is being done differently, very differently. So you need to be very precise about what you're trying to replicate.

Comment: @Confused, I have the images but stack overflow won't let me add them because i need at least 10 reputation, looking for a way to send you the images

Comment: @Confused **THE LINK FOR THE VIDEO IS:** https://youtu.be/j1052qNC9II?t=28s

Answer (score 0):

These are two different particle effects, which are best done with tens of thousands of very small particles, or even millions of them, in a post processing effects program like After Effects, using something like TrapCode's Particular, or similar. Then rendered out as low resolution image sequence animations, and composited where you need them, when you need them. You can get away with low resolution because they're wispy, additive and faint. This will be the most performant and common way to do this. Doing this with "real" particles on iOS will drain the battery and hog all the CPU and GPU to do the combination of physics and rendering required.

Comment: so after i render the animation, I add each image to the xcode project and then create texture atlas?

Comment: Yes... except you can create texture atlases by simply putting all the images into a folder with the extensions .atlas, and then importing that folder to xcode

Comment: Yes... except you can create texture atlases by simply putting all the images into a folder with the extensions .atlas, and then importing that folder to xcode